# jupyter notebooks slides: Skip as default

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

When using Jupyter for slides, is there a way to have **Slide Type** set to ***Skip*** for new cells, as a default?

[image]

Comment: Interesting question - I don't think there's an easy solution, though.

Answer (score 2):

My workaround for what you ask.
Create an empty "Skip" slide and type:
Esc 
C
V
V
V

To copy and paste many empty "Skip" slides.

Answer (score 1):

My workflow is as follows: I typically work on a notebook, do all the data explorations and only later I decide to convert it onto a slide-deck. This means setting the Slide Type to "Skip" (or "Sub-Slide") for *many cells*. It is unbearable to do it manually, so I go as follows:

- in notebook, switch on the View >> Cell Toolbar >> Slideshow; this brings up a field with drop-down menu (with options "Slide", "Sub-Slide", etc.) at the upper right corner of every cell. Initially there is no value selected in any cell; you could now go cell by cell and select an option manually, or work as follows:
- save and close the notebook
- open the ipynb file in a text editor, e.g. Notepad++
- find `"metadata": { }` and replace it by

```
"metadata": {
    "slideshow": {
     "slide_type": "subslide"
    }
```

(or `'slide_type_: "skip"` for skipping) .

In my version of Notepad++ it actually means to use this replace string:

```
"metadata": {\n    "slideshow": {\n     "slide_type": "subslide"\n    }\n    },
```

while having the Search mode switched to "Extended":
[image: noteapdplusplusreplace]