# Slideshow editing with Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

The new [Jupyter Lab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab) is great, but I am missing the option to turn cells into slides. In classic Jupyter Notebooks, that was under "View > Cell Toolbar > Slideshow":

[image]

What happened to the feature? Is there a way to edit slides in Jupyter Lab?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Jupyter Lab you can alter the 'slide type' in the 'Cell Inspector' menu.

Answer (score 15):

I have jupyter lab 1.1.4 installed on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and am using a python 3 virtual env kernel and it works great. Just complete your notebook and then configure each cell using the "Notebook Tools" tab on the far left (as shown in screenshot). Then save and close the notebook and run below command to output the slides.

[image]

Open the terminal and navigate to the recently saved .ipynb and run

```
jupyter nbconvert Untitled2.ipynb --to slides
```

For slides or say

```
jupyter nbconvert Untitled2.ipynb --to pdf
```

For a pdf

[image]

Note: You might need to install the Tex package to perfrom pdf outputs. See the docs [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex) or just run the below command to install it.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-generic-recommended
```

Cheers

Comment: I could not find this tab in JupyterLab 3.5.3. It seems that you now have to enable "View -> Show right sidebar" to show this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

It is still possible using `nbconvert`

[Presenting Code Using Jupyter Notebook Slides](https://medium.com/@mjspeck/presenting-code-using-jupyter-notebook-slides-a8a3c3b59d67)

command you need to run:

`jupyter nbconvert jupyter_notebook.ipynb --to slides --post serve`

Comment: However, this doesn’t give me the slideshow cell editing functionality I need in the notebook.

Comment: Some functionalities of the  jupyter notebook aren't ready yet in jupyter lab. Eventually the jupyter lab will replicate all good features of jupyter notebook and implement new others.

Comment: This works well I would just suggest running this from the notebook itself
`!jupyter nbconvert jupyter_notebook.ipynb --to slides --post serve`

Answer (score 0):

if you require the slideshow cell editing functionality you can either set it in the metadata as [explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635591/jupyter-notebooks-slides-skip-as-default/59704852#59704852), or you can switch from Lab to Notebook by going Help >> Launch Classic Notebook.

re:

> However, this doesn’t give me the slideshow cell editing functionality I need in the notebook.